# OpenStreetMap hide red tile overlay on 404

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm developing an application using OpenStreetMap that utilizes the OpenSeaMap tiles.  I can add the base 'Seamark' layers to my render fine, but because there are a lot of land tiles where there is no data available accessing these returns a 404 from the server, and they are rendered as a transparent red overlay on the map.

This looks ugly and is of no use, so I'd like to just ignore a 404 and not render the red 'missing tile' overlay.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your HTML head

```
<style>
    .olImageLoadError {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application using openstreetmap and seamarks from openseamap. However, it seems I do not have the problem you described.

[You can find the Project at here.](https://github.com/JonasGroeger/OSMDroidSeamarks) You will also find a screenshot at the page.